Ionic android app can't communicate with Express backend
I am trying to build my perfectly working ionic web app to android. The app launches, but can't communicate with my Express backend. I get this error :
Msg: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://{{ip}}:3000/getGroupsNameOfUser'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(with getGroupsNameOfUser being a app.post() of my express server, and {{ip}} the local ip of the computer runing express that I prefer not to share just in case).
I understand that my android app is in https and doesn't like to communicate with a server in http.
To solve this, I have tried enabling mixed content by adding this line in AndroidManifest.xml:
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but it just doesn't work (I still get the same error).
I have then tried by adding a network_security_config.xml in res/xml/, filled with :
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.15:3000</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://127.0.0.1:3000</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

And adding this line in AndroidManifest.xml : android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" but it doesn't work either...
I have then tried the recommended solution: putting my express server on ssl. I created self-signed keys with this command : sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt. I had an error when using them so I used a command I found online : sudo chmod 755 selfsigned.key.
I then wrote my main js script:
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('keys/selfsigned.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('keys/selfsigned.crt')
};

const app = express ();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.use(cookieParser());


... (multiple app.post(...))


https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS server listening on port 3000');
});

Finally I changed the adress used in my ionic app with HttpClient to "https://{{ip}}:3000/".
But it still doesn't work. I get this error :
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

2024-05-25 12:08:30.335 22173-22173 Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     E  File: https://localhost/main.262cd90795cda89d.js - Line 1 - Msg: ERROR [object Object]

2024-05-25 12:08:31.178  1588-2373  VerityUtils             system_server                        E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~DnQFZdmZ2tBOfRYWJyZ4Rw==/io.ionic.starter-bZlHBiUj6Wi4udiAfuiCCA==/base.apk

2024-05-25 12:08:31.306  1588-2373  VerityUtils             system_server                        E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~DnQFZdmZ2tBOfRYWJyZ4Rw==/io.ionic.starter-bZlHBiUj6Wi4udiAfuiCCA==/base.apk

I don't understand if the issue is from my backend or my app. I have tried "converting" my key to der with this command : openssl x509 -outform der -in selfsigned.crt -out server.der and adding the file to my phone's trusted certificates. But it still doesn't do anything.
Since I can do post requests with postman on https://localhost:3000, I suppose that my express works correctly, at least locally. I have tried with postman on another computer, and it works to if I disable ssl verification. If I try with the webapp (launch with ionic serve --ssl), I get a cors error that I can't manage to solve, but I won't care as long as my android app works, which it still does not T.T.
I am completely desperate, I don't know what else to try. Can anyone help me ?

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true})); is insecure. Never use such a dangerous CORS configuration, no matter how desperate you are to fix your CORS issues.

Besides, the error has nothing to do with CORS and everything to do with mixed content: modern browsers block https documents from requesting http resources.

@jub0bs I do know that this is dangerous and not recommended. I will change this as soon as my application can communicate my express again.
But like you said, this problem has nothing not with cors. Like I said, even after putting my express server on https, the application can't communicate with it. Do you have an idea on how to solve this ?

The problem is that you cannot have https with an IP address. For HTTPS, you need a domain and a TLS cert for it.

@jub0bs oh ok, do you know if it is possible to have an express server with a domain (without requiring a CA, this is just a school project, not something that is going to be on any app store).

@jub0bs I just remembered: I was able to send requests to my express server with the https://{{ip}}:3000/ url, so I am not sure that this is really the problem. I just had to tell postman to not check ssl. Why would I be unable to do this with my app if I can do it with Postman ? (thank you very much for helping btw)

Postman != browser

@jub0bs But how are you supposed to develop an Android app if you're supposed to have an already perfectly functional backend with a signed certificate and a host ?

You can absolutely do testing on a localhost, I just use this config:
server.listen(PORT, '192.168.1.7', function () { });
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

app.use(
cors({
origin: [
"capacitor://localhost",
"http://localhost",
"http://localhost:8100",
],
})
);
and I stick to the http://192.168.1.7:8443 on my project (which is my machine's wifi assigned ip)
